# Форма обратной связи без php

Tags: формы

Есть сайт, доступа к внутрянке нет, но есть возможность создавать странички и добавлять на них html(+css) и js. PHP не работает и доступ к нему отсутствует. Какие есть возможности добавить форму обратной связи?

Comment: Google Forms?.. )

Comment: Хм. Не знал что у них есть форма с отправкой почты, зашел, увидел там создание опросников и вышел. Думаю такой вариант подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

Ты не можешь отправить сообщение на почту без использования серверной части, единственное что можно сделать так это создать ссылку с атрибутом ,`mailto:` либо кнопку после клика по которой запустить клиентское приложение для отправки почты `window.open('mailto:test@example.com');`